# List Maven Dependencies which would prevent a release

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to find a way to get maven to list all dependencies which would cause a release to fail. I would like to avoid doing a `release:prepare` with a `-DdryRun` as I don't want the check to do a complete build, I just want it to resolve the dependencies and check for SNAPSHOTS

Using the dependencies plugin and doing a list-dependencies is not ideal as that will include any sub-project snapshots - which would not prevent a `release:prepare` from succeeding.

Answer (score 1):

The [maven-enforcer-plugin with requireReleaseDeps rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireReleaseDeps.html) may be what you are looking for. According to the enforcer plugin documentation the **requireReleaseDeps** rule:

> This rule checks the dependencies and fails if any snapshots are found.

It supports several parameters for how to search for snapshots.

Also according to the the [maven-enforcer-plugin mojo documentation](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html)

> Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: validate.

which is the first phase in the default lifecycle so it will not do a build if there are snapshots

Comment: Unfortunately this does not correctly ignore the reactor projects which would be up-versioned by a `release:prepare`, unless there's an option that I've missed

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `enforcer` plugin, it has a standard rule called `requireReleaseDeps`.

Full details are available [here](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireReleaseDeps.html%20here).

As always, you can put this plugin's activation in a profile if you want.